# Why is it called 'renewable energy'?

Tags: terminology, word-usage

There's a lot of buzz these days about 'renewable energy', and with Germany's recent decision to close down their nuclear plants by 2012, activists are talking about moving to completely 'renewable energy'.  But, why is it called that?  What is actually being renewed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Renewable energy* is energy made from a *renewable resource*.  A *renewable resource* is one which will (or can easily be made to) reappear given ordinary processes that will run pretty much unchanged for millions of years.

Thus, copper is not a renewable resource because we mine it from the ground and don't put it back where we got it; wood is a renewable resource because trees will just grow again (as long as we don't let all the topsoil wash off).

Hydroelectric power is renewable because rain keeps falling in catchment areas.  Nuclear power is not renewable because radioactive isotopes don't appear in the ground again.

It is entirely possible to exhaust a renewable resource: you can cut down all your trees, empty out your reservoir, etc..  What makes them renewable is not that they're inexhaustable, but that they'll be back.  (At least given some sensible precautions.)

Comment: Thanks; this was basically what I suspected.  Renewable energy is not *strictly* renewable.

Comment: @Jez - The Second Law of Thermodynamics says that _nothing_ is renewable, strictly speaking.  Since we don't care overly much about the entropy of outer space, we can use the word "renewable" in the context of our planet in an informative way.

Answer (score 3):

> Renewable energy is energy which comes from natural resources such as sunlight, wind, rain, tides, and geothermal heat, which are renewable (naturally replenished).

Basically, you can't "run out of wind", therefore the wind energy is renewable, because the wind will blow again, but you can "run out of trees", therefore wood is not renewable.

One could argue that philosophically you can run out of wind, but that would be very difficult and isn't really possible, at least will not be caused by turning the wind into energy.

The *energy source* is what is being renewed and this isn't really a part of the process of turning the energy source to the energy. That's what might have confused you.

Comment: As you said, you can indeed 'run out of wind'.  When you convert wind energy into electricity you are removing energy from the atmosphere. If anything, I'd actually say wood was more renewable than wind energy; you can plant new trees and have a pretty much endless cycle.

Comment: You are being too strict here. The OP has asked the definition of renewable energy, not whether it's wrong. I can't argue = you are right, but you are missing one point. You are talking about "taking the energy from the wind and not giving it back to the universe, therefore running out of wind", then you go on saying you can "plant new trees and they will grow." No, they won't grow, if you don't give the energy back, like the first scenario. You are not being consistent in your statements.

Comment: @Jez: No, you can't run out of wind, not even if you use it to produce energy. Wind is simply air movement determined by different air pressions and heat (the Sun), it's not something concrete. There will always be wind until the sun and the air will exist, so for a long time yet. Trees can be re-planted, sure, but how long does it take to a tree to become "adult" and therefore useful for wood? Not to mention that burning wood is more polluting than using wind to produce energy.

Answer (score 0):

The source is considered to renew itself. It also makes a nice contrast to "consumable" sources.

More accurately, the sources are renewed by (a) the sun (b) coriolis energy (c) geothermal processes.

Comment: The sun will eventually run out of energy, and nothing is being renewed; rather it's being expended.  Geothermal processes on Earth are again expending energy as the Earth cools down.  And coriolis energy is also produced as a result of the gradual slowing down of the Earth's rotation; its source is also being expended.  Not renewed.

Comment: @Jez: And your point is?

Comment: None of them is truly renewable, and so it seems to be a term founded in fundamental misconception.

Comment: @Jez If the sun burns out, life on Earth is finished. If oil runs out, we can turn to something else. I'd say that's a large enough difference to squash your quibble.

Comment: @Jez: Those forces are renewed by the energy from the sources mentioned. Just because the sources providing the energy are merely extremely large and long-lived but finite does not mean that no renewal is occurring.

Comment: @Marcin How is renewal occurring in the sun?  If your radiator is heating the air around it, would you say it's producing heat, or that the heat is being 'renewed'?  Would the heat be 'renewable'?

Comment: @Jez: That's a specious analogy, and you know it. The sources that we use are renewed are from other sources, and that is the renewal that occurs. That renewal will continue to occur for longer than the length of recorded history (and in fact longer than the time in which hominids are estimated to have existed). If that's too short for your plans, I suggest you take your tardis elsewhere.

Comment: I don't deny I'm trying to be rather precise here, but considering there is a plethora of words to choose from to describe this energy, I'm a bit bemused that what has caught on is, at least technically, a misnomer.  One wants to say that this energy is going to be around for a Very Long Time, or not give off pollutants that we don't like, so terms like 'enduring' or 'green' energy seem fine.  But 'renewable' grates on me a bit.

Comment: @Jez: It's not a misnomer, technically, or otherwise. The supply is actually being renewed.

Comment: Then it's 'renewed energy'.  It's not renew **able**.  One cannot (or does not) renew **it**.

Comment: @Jez: If something is renewed, then it is capable of being renewed. The word for being capable of being renewed is "renewable".

Comment: @Marcin I see your point.  I guess the part where I think the term is misleading is where people call it 'renewable energy' rather than a 'renewable energy supply'.  This is rather lazy terminology.  As you said, it's the supply that's being renewed, not the energy.

Answer (score 0):

Renewable energy is more along the lines of being a layman's term. Speaking in terms of physics with regards to the laws of thermodynamics, energy can not be created or destroyed. It should rather be coined as 'recyclable energy' but that is also borderline of being a layman term.

The term renewable energy references the growth or procurement and usance of sustainable resources to provide a form of energy to meet our needs and wants.